# Displaying data with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am passing an Alert Entity to my view, and this Entity has access to an Availability Entity.  So to get access to an Alerts Availability, I can do something like

```
{% for alert in alerts %}
    {% for availability in alert.getAvailability %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

getAvailability will essentially return an Array Collection of Availability Objects.  To give you an idea of what data these Objects contain, I have created 2 alerts (with id's 11 and 12).  When these Alerts are created, Availability is created for that alert.  So the data I have is

```
id | alert_id | class_letter | alert_pseudo | flight_number | availability | last_updated
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 11       | C            | 1E3          | VS7           | 9            | 26/02/2015  12:16:06
 2 | 11       | D            | 1E3          | VS7           | 9            | 26/02/2015  12:16:06
 3 | 11       | C            | 1E3          | VS7           | 9            | 26/02/2015  13:16:06
 4 | 11       | D            | 1E3          | VS7           | 6            | 26/02/2015  13:16:06
 5 | 12       | E            | 1E3          | BA5           | 6            | 26/02/2015  12:16:06
 6 | 12       | I            | 1E3          | BA5           | 9            | 26/02/2015  12:16:06
```

So at 12:16:06, Availability was created for C and D class, and at 13:16:06 another lot of Availability was created for them.  Essentially, all the data I need is in this table, I just need to figure out how to arrange it.

What I am looking for is something like this

```
Alert #11

                                           VS7
                                            C       D
26/02/2015  12:16:06                        9       9          
26/02/2015  13:16:06                        9       6


Alert #12

                                           BA5
                                            E       I
26/02/2015  12:16:06                        6       9
```

Now to achieve something like the above, I could essentially do something along the lines of

```
<div class="panel-body">
    {% set i = 0 %}
    {% set j = 0 %}

    {% for alert in alerts %}

        <h3 class='alert-header'>Alert #{{ alert.id }}</h3>

        <div class="availability_table_container">
            <table class="availability_table">
                {% for pseudo in alert.getPseudos %}
                    {% for flight in alert.getFlightNumbers %}
                        <tr>
                            {% if j == 0 %}
                                <th></th>
                            {% endif %}
                            <th class='class-header'>{{ flight.getFlightNumber }}</th>
                            {% set j = j + 1 %}
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            {% for class in alert.getBookingClasses %}
                                {% if i == 0 %}
                                    <th></th>
                                {% endif %}
                                <th class='pseudo-header'>{{ class.getClassLetter }}</th>

                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        {% for date in alert.getAvailability %}
                            <tr>
                                {% if i == 0 %}
                                    <td class='time_row'>{{ date.getLastUpdated|date('d M Y H:00') }}</td>
                                {% endif %}

                                {% for avail in alert.getAvailability %}
                                    <td>{{ avail.getAvailability }}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}

                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% set i = i + 1 %}
</div>
```

Now that nearly works, but the output I get is

```
Alert #11

                                           VS7
                                            C       D
26/02/2015  12:16:06                        9       9 9 6   
26/02/2015  12:16:06                        9       9 9 6
26/02/2015  13:16:06                        9       9 9 6
26/02/2015  13:16:06                        9       9 9 6


Alert #12

                                           BA5
                                            E       I
26/02/2015  12:16:06                        6       9           
26/02/2015  12:16:06                        6       9
```

So to start, it is giving me too many dates.  It should be one date for each collection of classes.  The other problem is the availability.  It seems to output all the availability numbers for each row, instead of just displaying its own.

Is there any way to make this closer to what I require?  More importantly, is it ok doing all of this in Twig?

Thanks

Comment: As you have discovered, twig does not work well for this sort of thing.  Make yourself a twig extension (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html), pass it your alerts and have it return a properly organized array.  BTW, you seem to be asking quite a few questions without responding to the answers.  Not good for soliciting support.  I only read this one because it's a boring snow day.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will have a look into it.  I normally reply to questions, just havnt got round to it yet today although I have marked some up.  Will go have a look at the other ones presently.  Thanks